# wp_editor Too Tall when Content is Loaded

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor

I am using the code below to load a custom editor for my application:

```
<?php wp_editor(stripslashes($post->post_content),"project_description",array('quicktags'=>false, 'textarea_rows'=>10, "media_buttons"=>false));?>
```

This code works fine until content is loaded into the editor. For some reason the editor will stretch to ridiculous heights (14,000 px) even if there is only 1 sentence in the editor. It is also inconsistent - sometimes it loads properly, but most of the time it does not.

Also, as soon as anything is entered into the editor after loading it resizes to the proper height. It seems like some kind of initialization problem (calculating the wrong init height). I have seen this in several other instances as well, but I don't seem to be able to find a solution.

**Before Keypress:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Va4Sz.jpg
[image]

**After Keypress:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbfBx.jpg
[image]

Comment: Does this still happen, after you [disabled all plugins and switched to one of the Twenty* themes?](http://i.imgur.com/wScmw.png) Please follow the linked process to identify the conflicting plugin or theme.

Comment: Can you provide more context? Where are you calling `wp_editor`? What does the surrounding code look like? What screen is this being shown on? Frontend? Backend? Can you take screenshots?

Comment: I disabled all my plugins and the issue persists. I cannot disable my theme because the editor that is having the issue is generated by my custom theme files.

Comment: This particular editor is located in a custom admin page, but I have had the same issue on the public side of the site as well.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?